# Conditions for a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

In my topology notes the definition is given as:

A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be a homeomorphism if: $f$ is continuous, bijective, and moreover its inverse $f^{−1} : Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

My question is: Does the fact that $f$ has an inverse not already guarantee that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: It guarantees its inverse, which does not mean it is necessarily continuous.

Comment: If you'd define "$f$ is continuous and its inverse ..." your audience would interrupt you and shout "What inverse? Do you mean $f$ is in fact bijective? Or injective and you mean left inverse? Or surjective and you mean right inverse? But those are not even unique in general! Help, I'm lost!". You *might* shorten to "$f$ is continuous and has a continuous two-sided inverse". Or, more leaning towards category theory: "$f$ is continuous and there exists continuous $g\colon Y\to X$ with $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$ and $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $f$ is bijective ensures that $f^{-1}$ is a valid function from $Y$ to $X$. We now want *both* $f$ and $f^{-1}$ to be continuous, and the latter is not automatic from the former (consider the identity between $X$ in the discrete topology to $X$ in a non-discrete topology, e.g.). So we demand them separately.

We could just say $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous, but then we'd be implicitly assuming the bijectivity of $f$ by just "using" a function $f^{-1}$. It's better to be explicit here, and state the bijectiveness separately. Hence the order: $f$ continuous, bijective (so that $f^{-1}$ is a valid function!) and finally this function $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ is also continuous.